# Regex to extract sub string from complex string

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8, substring

I've a string that can have in two formats,

**First Format:**

```
route-policy testPolicy
  if (destination in pfx_manju) then
    set extcommunity rt (10429:103) additive
  endif
end-policy
```

**Second Format:**

```
route-policy testPolicy
  if (destination in EXP1) then
    set extcommunity rt (27699:352002, 2.2.2.2:98) additive
  elseif (destination in pfx_manju) then
    set extcommunity rt (27699:339600, 27679:339700, 1.1.1.1:6763, 65536:45633) additive
  elseif (destination in EXP5) then
    drop
  endif
end-policy
```

**Third Format:**

```
route-policy EXPORTRP1
  if (destination in EXP1) or (destination in EXP2) then
    set extcommunity rt (27699:352002, 2.2.2.2:98) additive
  elseif (destination in pfx_manju) or (destination in EXP4) then
    set extcommunity rt (27699:339600, 27679:339700, 1.1.1.1:6763, 65536:45633) additive
  elseif (destination in EXP5) or (destination in EXP6) then
    drop
  endif
end-policy
```

So here the complete text is coming as string. The string either single condition (if) or multiple conditions (elseIf conditions).

From the above string I want to extract the rt values for one hard coded policy (pfx_manju). I can extract the rt values with below regex,

```
final String regex = "rt \\(([^)]+)\\)";
```

Now the problem is, I want to extract the sub string which is belongs to the hard coded policy (pfx_manju).

So condition is get a sub string with starting position is index of **pfx_manju** and ending position is the subsequent **endif** or **elseif**.

So I want the sub sting output for above examples as mentioned below,

**First Sub String:**

```
  pfx_manju) then
    set extcommunity rt (10429:103) additive
```

Second Sub String:

```
pfx_manju) then
        set extcommunity rt (27699:339600, 27679:339700, 1.1.1.1:6763, 65536:45633) additive
```

**Third Sub String:**

```
pfx_manju) or (destination in EXP4) then
        set extcommunity rt (27699:339600, 27679:339700, 1.1.1.1:6763, 65536:45633) additive
```

Any suggestions with optimistic solution will be appreciated

Comment: is the substring you gave, the string you want to extract?

Comment: Yes.. The string I mentioned is what I should extract

Comment: Cary Swoveland, Yes, String will always contains one condition with "prx_manju", If string doesn't contains the "prx_manju", I will not process any thing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should work

```
pfx_manju\)[\s\S]*?rt \(([^)]+)\) additive
```

The regex matches string starting from `pfx_manju` condition all the way to `rt` values, that means it captures the rt values when there is only `pfx_manju` condition. if you are using java, you need to scape, `\`.

See regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/flJTGq/3)

Comment: ok, I guess the string always has the condition  `pfx_manju` as you mentioned

Comment: Updated the question with all possibilities and added the comment with conformation

Comment: Yes, Tried your suggestion. Thank you for you time and inputs